# use .where() Query with .update() via mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I use `.where()` with `.update()` in mongoose? The query conditions are the first argument passed .update(). Should I pass `null` for the query condition to `.update()` and follow it with a `.where('_id', id)`? Also, can I apply this to `.findByIdAndUpdate()`/`.findOneAndUpdate()` as well?

If not, is there a `Query` method in which I can `.update()` with just the update document and specify the conditions via other `.where()` methods in the chain?

Comment: Can you explain more explicitly what your intent is? From your DB, what files are you trying to retrieve, and what files are you trying to update?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `where` on a Model class returns a `Query` object which has the sort of methods you're asking about: `update`, `findOneAndUpdate`.

So you can chain them together to do things like:

```
MyModel.where('_id', id).update({$set: {foo: 'bar'}}, function (err, count) {});
```

Comment: Does that mean the doc passed into `.update()` is for the update document and not the query conditions?http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update