# Update many in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very simple case. I want to update my collection every midnight.
Im using `node-schedule`:

```
schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 * * *', () => {
   Users.updateMany();
});
```

All I want to do, is to loop over every document in my collection (`Users`) and then if `User.created` is `false`, I want to turn it into `true`.

In javascript it would be:

```
for (let user in Users) {
   if (user.created === false) {
      user.created = true;
   }
}
```

How to do it in mongoose? Thanks!

#### **Edit**: The story is very simple, I just want to iterate over every element in my db using mongoose and if iterated element has field "created" === false, change it to true.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729831/use-where-query-with-update-via-mongoose

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser Will it work on many elements? Or just one?

Comment: Did you click through to the question and read it and the answer? I believe it's all there. I recommend searching for "mongoose update where" to update all documents that match a where clause in Mongoose.

Comment: FYI, assuming `created` is a required property, your example doesn't need a condition. You're just trying to set `created: true` for every user.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You first need a query to find the documents you want to update. This is simply:

```
{"created": false}
```

Then you need an update query to tell mongo how to update those documents:

```
{"$set":{"created": true}}
```

You need to use the `$set` operator to specify which fields to change, otherwise it will overwrite the entire document. Finally you can combine these components into a single mongo call with an additional parameter to tell mongo we want to modify multiple documents:

```
User.update({"created": false}, {"$set":{"created": true}}, {"multi": true}, (err, writeResult) => {});
```

Mongoose tries to closely replicate the mongo API so all this information can be found solely within MongoDB's documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Thanks, but I need solution in mongoose

Comment: @Patrickkx, the answer is mongoose. I've slightly edited it to reflect your code snippets

Comment: What is `writeResult`? What if I only want to add "created" : true only for selected entries? Like only for these, where `date > 100`? How to add a condition?

Comment: @Patrickkx you can write anything in place of `writeResult` like doc ..`doc) => {
                if (doc) return res.send(doc);` . For date you need to put in `if` condition.

Comment: await User.updateMany({ created: false }, {"$set":{"created": true}} ). 
Just this will work! You can use async/await if you want to wait for either success or error. With mongoose updateMany() you do not need the {multi:true} in the options. I used this before to update multiple docs

Answer (score 89):

You can use **`updateMany()`** methods of mongodb to update multiple document

Simple query is like this

```
db.collection.updateMany(filter, update, options)
```

For more doc of uppdateMany read [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany)

As per your **requirement** the update **code** will be like this:

```
User.updateMany({"created": false}, {"$set":{"created": true}});
```

here you need to use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) because you just want to change created from true to false. For ref. If you want to change entire doc then you don't need to use **$set**

Comment: Thanks! What If I want to add some condition? For all those entries which "created" is false? Something like: `({ created: false }, () => { if (selected.date > 100) { do something } })`?

Comment: For that you need to use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/)