# update multiple records in one query in MongoDB NodeJS without any loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have array of objects and I want update all records in one query

```
var arrayObj=[
         {id:'5e346213bec252771415a9ee',
         status:1,
         date:01-2-2020},{id:'5e346213bec252471415a9efr',
         status:2,
         date:02-2-2020},
         {id:'5e346213bec252771415a9ee',
         status:3,
         date:01-3-2020}];

Leads.update();
```

I am new to node and mongo, how can I update this. I don't want to use loop, as I have done with loop. Now I want to learn this.

Comment: i am waiting for reply...please reply friends

Comment: This question were solved here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992810/update-many-in-mongoose

Comment: thanks for your comment....please read my question.....your refread link dose not full fill my requirment

Comment: i have different values against each records...

Comment: @rpereira15 i want update all records with its own value

Comment: Actually, your need are not so explicit. You do not informed what do you want update. But, i really shure that link will be enough. You just need to execute a query without filter  passing what filds who you want update.

Comment: @rpereira15     var arrayObj=[
         {id:'5e346213bec252771415a9ee',
         status:1,
         date:01-2-2020},{id:'5e346213bec252471415a9efr',
         status:2,
         date:02-2-2020},
         {id:'5e346213bec252771415a9ee',
         status:3,
         date:01-3-2020}];

Leads.update(arrayOb);

Comment: is it right syntax to update all array records

Comment: these ids are exist in db and have other valuse...now i want to update new values

Comment: You can't do this. There's not support on mongo or mongoose for this. In some moment someone will do a loop (or you do or framework do). Look mongo doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update and mongoose doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating

Comment: respected  @rpereira15  i didnt understand on this links description.i have told in my question i am begner in this field....can you make a proper example for me according to my question requirement..i will be very thankful of you.

Comment: i have stuck badly in this scenario...i have searched a lot but unable to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

What I trying to say, are:

1. You can't bulk update in this way, just passing many objects to some  magic function.
2. MongoDb are a document oriented database, so, it's not normalised. To update some document, you need pass instructions (where you want to update and what you want to update).
3. If you have an array, you need a loop function to update each array item.
4. There's no possibility (without some third part library), to update many documents without loop. The links I sent explains the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bulk operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/).

```
var bulkOpr = <collectionName>.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulkOpr.find({ _id: 1 }).updateOne({ /* update document */ });
bulkOpr.find({ _id: 2 }).updateOne({ /* update document */ });
// etc

bulkOp.execute();
```

You can do whatever you need to and the database do it all at once.

**Ref. links:**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/unordered.html

Comment: With this solution, he need a loop yet. The bulk strategy just execute all updates at the same time.

Comment: @rpereira15 loop only for preparing query, bulk operations executes only once.

Comment: I agree with this approach, but, if you read comments from Ali, him does not want to build a loop. His want mount an array and pass this to update.